# Typing return type of React components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

[This PR](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177) to Create-React-App removes `React.FC` as the return type for components (for the reasoning why, see the PR). Does this mean that ESlint's [explicit function return type](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md) rule should no longer apply to React components? If so, how would one go about keeping ESlint happy?

Comment: Did you get into some problem?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `React.ReactElement | null` as the return type of your function components. That's what `React.FC` does today.

```
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const MyComponent = ({ children }: Props): React.ReactElement => (
  <div>{children}</div>
)
```

Comment: `ReactNode` also includes `undefined` which is not allowed. Returning `undefined` would cause React to throw `Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to declare your function as a `ComponentType` instead, which encapsulates a return type:

```
import { ComponentType } from 'react';

const App: ComponentType<AppProps> = () => (
  <div>Whatever</div>
);
```